# javascript proper way to call function

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm not good in javascript but I find examples and usually understand it. But this is driving me crazy for the last hour. What I'm trying to do is to embed the list.php file to my mainpage.html using the IFRAME. This list.php is showing some links and when I click the link the result should be shown in another place on main page (I'm targeting some div). And those 3 functions are placed inside list.php file.

If I do this:

```
   function autoscroll() {
       window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0);
   }
   function resizeIframe(obj) {
       obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
   }
   function url2div(url,target){
       parent.document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this); javascript:autoscroll();" src="' + url + '" />';
   }
```

So if I call the autoscroll() function within my IFRAME like this

```
onload="javascript:autoscroll();"
```

autoscroll doesn't work (everything else is working).

But if I put it directly in IFRAME like this:

```
onload="javascript:window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0);"
```

then it works!

What's wrong with first approach?

Comment: Show the relevant DOM.

Comment: Are you putting the script above in the iframe or parent frame?

Comment: I'm putting it in the file which is embedded to the parent page via IFRAME

Comment: Is the problem maybe that I'm using this IFRAME as a part of another function? What I'm trying to do is to embed the list.php file to my mainpage.html using the IFRAME. This list.php is showing some links and when I click the link the result should be shown in another place on main page (I'm targeting some div). And those 3 functions are placed inside list.php file.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're putting the `script` element in your main page, but then trying to use it in an `iframe` on the page. Also, you're using `window.parent.parent` which goes two levels up the containment hierarchy, which seems suspicious.

The `iframe` and the main window are two different environments. Globals (like your `autoscroll`) in the main page are not in scope for the `iframe`'s code.

The `iframe` can access the parent window's globals, provided they're from the same origin, via the `parent` symbol:

```
parent.autoscroll();
```

Then use `window`, or `window.paren`, depending on whether you want to scroll the parent or *its* parent.

It's all about being relative to the document in which the script is included.

Since that was clear as mud: Let's assume your goal is to scroll the main window that the `iframe` is in:

**Option 1**: Put it in the `iframe` (probably best):

In the main window:

Nothing.

In the `iframe`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function autoscroll() {
       window.parent.scrollTo(0,0); // <== Only one `parent`, if you want the iframe's parent
   }
</script>
```

and

```
onload="autoscroll();"
```

**Or**:

**Option 2**: Put it in the main window:

In the main window:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function autoscroll() {
       window.scrollTo(0,0); // <== No `parent` at all, if you want the main window
   }
</script>
```

In the `iframe`:

```
onload="parent.autoscroll();"
```

Comment: Hi T.J.I have updated the original post. I'm looking at your answer and its all sounds like it should work but it doesn't in my case. Is the problem maybe that I'm using this IFRAME as a part of another function? What I'm trying to do is to embed the list.php file to my mainpage.html  using the IFRAME. This list.php is showing some links and when I click the link the result should be shown in another place on main page (I'm targeting some div). And those 3 functions are placed inside list.php file.